# Communicate with a computer without knowing its address

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I am looking for a technique where I can communicate (basically send some command) to a remote PC (probably connected with internet) but I don't have any idea about its IP address. So how can I do that. I am willing to find this for windows XP/7 platform. If anybody has any idea. Please share.

One more note to be added here: The receiver side should not have any client side application for this communication.

Comment: What kind of message or command do you want to send? What is the protocol? If the receiver does not have an application, will it be a windows command that the OS can understand ?  Please provide some specifics about your scenario so that people can help better.

Comment: I want to send a command to run an application like opening camera and stream video from it. I have an application that needs to take pictures of client from remote pc. I need to do that.

Comment: You're pretty much asking how to write a virus

Answer (score 5):

From your description, this isn't possible.

Using a metaphor, you want to call someone, without knowing their phone number, and you don't want them to have a phone.  That just isn't possible.

Comment: Actually it is like inter-process communication in multiple PC. And I was trying to find out if there is any other identity for a pc over internet other than IP

Comment: If your definition for the internet is "Computers connected to networks AND routers across company and telecommunication entities" then the only route-able protocol on the internet is IP (thusly named Internet Protocol).  There are other protocols that are route-able, but only by the company the chooses to use them (IPX, Netbeui, etc).